# Wavy / Curvy Module's

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently working on a website that has a modular design with text modules, image modules, 2 column modules... and the user can add / remove / reorder them however they like.

Each module has a wavy / curvy border:
[image: module example]

Is it possible to make something like this with css?

Each module would overlap:

[image]

One solution I came up with was to give the modules a wavy / curvy background image before and after the div and give them a negative margin but soon realised that would would not work with image modules:

```
.module.style-2 {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC7gAAAABAQMAAAB0GXF9AAAABlBMVEX////09PQtDxrOAAAAD0lEQVQY02P4PygBw3AHAG6mlWu52WYpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: 40% 0; 
}

.module.style-2:before {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-image: url('top-curvy-background-1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 0; 
}

.module.style-2:after {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-image: url('bottom-curvy-background-1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-position: 40% 0; 
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chriswatts91/pen/yJVXzB)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 ways worth exploring:

1. Css have property called clip path [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/). You can use it to use non standard containers.
2. SVG, especially tag clipPath which might give you more flexibility [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)
3. Use predefined backgrounds, however make the rule no two image modules are attached to them self. This way you can use z-index for the plain colour modules to always be on top, de facto allowing image to be cropped by your backgrounds. You can even make those shapes with svg's to make tiny as well as administrable from html/css level (you can create new shapes dynamically).

Good luck and tell me what you decided for ;)

Comment: Only issue with clip paths is support with IE: http://codepen.io/chriswatts91/pen/beBxLV?editors=1100

Comment: Yes, that will be the case unfortunately. 3 solution is most widely supported,but have limitations. 2 is a lot harder, but can give the best results.

Comment: What solution did you end up with? Curiosity :)